# SQL - How can I combine 3 similar queries into one?

Tags: sql

The following 3 queries differ only in the `WHERE` clauses with different date ranges.

I'd like to know if I can get the same data with one query, or some other way to improve performance.

```sql
left join (
    select
        mi.acIdent,
        m.acissuer,
        sum(mi.anQty) q
    from the_moveitem mi
        left join the_move m on mi.acKey = m.acKey
    where m.adDate between getdate() - (365 * 1) and getdate() - (365 * 1 - @days)  -- <--- THIS PART
    group by
        mi.acident,
        m.acIssuer
) soldNextDaysOneYearAgo
    on soldNextDaysOneYearAgo.acIdent = s.acIdent and soldNextDaysOneYearAgo.acIssuer = s.acWarehouse

left join (
    select
        mi.acIdent,
        m.acissuer,
        sum(mi.anQty) q
    from the_moveitem mi
        left join the_move m on mi.acKey = m.acKey
    where m.adDate between getdate() - (365 * 2) and getdate() - (365 * 2 - @days)  -- <--- THIS PART
    group by
        mi.acident,
        m.acIssuer
) soldNextDaysTwoYearsAgo
    on soldNextDaysTwoYearsAgo.acIdent = s.acIdent and soldNextDaysTwoYearsAgo.acIssuer = s.acWarehouse

left join (
    select
        mi.acIdent,
        m.acissuer,
        sum(mi.anQty) q
    from the_moveitem mi
        left join the_move m on mi.acKey = m.acKey
    where m.adDate between getdate() - (365 * 3) and getdate() - (365 * 3 - @days)  -- <--- THIS PART
    group by
        mi.acident,
        m.acIssuer
) soldNextDaysThreeYearsAgo
    on soldNextDaysThreeYearsAgo.acIdent = s.acIdent and soldNextDaysThreeYearsAgo.acIssuer = s.acWarehouse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a conditional `Sum`

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1
left join (
    select
        mi.acIdent,
        m.acissuer,
        sum(CASE WHEN  m.adDate between getdate() - (365 * 1) and getdate() - (365 * 1 - @days) THEN mi.anQty ELSE 0 END) q1
        ,sum(CASE WHEN  m.adDate between getdate() - (365 * 2) and getdate() - (365 * 2 - @days) THEN mi.anQty ELSE 0 END) q2
        ,sum(CASE WHEN  m.adDate between getdate() - (365 * 3) and getdate() - (365 * 3 - @days) THEN mi.anQty ELSE 0 END) q3
    from the_moveitem mi
        left join the_move m on mi.acKey = m.acKey

    group by
        mi.acident,
        m.acIssuer
) soldNextDaysOneYearAgo
    on soldNextDaysOneYearAgo.acIdent = s.acIdent and soldNextDaysOneYearAgo.acIssuer = s.acWarehouse
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much! Interestingly enough, the execution time is identical, however the query complexity is reduced significantly.

Comment: the problem is that all rows must be checked as you have no where clause, it would much faster when you add the missing where clause

Comment: Are you saying that I should add all the cases in an OR where clause as well? i.e. add the max and min dates from the cases.

Comment: you should test it with for examp,le `MONTH(m.adDate) = MONTH(getdate())` this would reduce the number of row to  a twelfth of its size, also a `YEAR(m.adDate) > YEAR(getdate()) - 3` and teh same goes for dates no OR clause needed, you should give it a try and see with explain, it the time changes